# Error deleting name from linked list in c

Tags: c, loops, struct, linked-list, singly-linked-list

So, the program takes the names entered by the user, displays those names and removes a name that the user wants.
The problem is that when I type a name that wasn't entered, it removes the last name that was entered in the list.

Struct:

```
struct node
{
    char name[50];
    struct node *next;
}*node;
```

remove function:

```
void remove(){
   char nameToDelete[50];
   struct node *temp, *previous;
   temp = node;

   printf("What is the name you wish to delete?\n");
   scanf("%s", nameToDelete);

   for ( ; temp->next != NULL; temp = temp->next )
   {
      previous = temp;
      if(strcmp(nameToDelete, temp->name)==0)
      {
         break;
      }
   }

   if ( temp == node )
   {
      node = temp->next;
   }
   else
   {
      previous->next = temp->next;
   }

   free(temp);
   printf("%s was deleted successfully\n", nameToDelete);
}
```

.

Comment: When you exit the loop, `previous` and `temp` are the same, right?  Can you see why that won't work?  You need to set `previous` *before* advancing `temp`.

Comment: You have to check whether you reached the end of the list without finding the name.

Comment: `scanf("%s", nameToDelete);` is [as dangerous as `gets`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used). Limit your input length to avoid exceeding your buffer size: `scanf("%49s", nameToDelete);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this loop

```
for ( ; temp->next != NULL; temp = temp->next )
{
   previous = temp;
   if(strcmp(nameToDelete, temp->name)==0)
   {
      break;
   }
}
```

if the name to be deleted is not found then the third expression of the loop `temp = temp->next` is evaluated and after the loop the pointer `temp` points to the last node that then is deleted in this code snippet

```
//...
else
{
   previous->next = temp->next;
}

free(temp);
```

Another problem is if the name to be deleted is found then the pointers `previous` and `temp` are equal each other due to the break statement

Also the function should initially check whether the pointer `node` is equal to `NULL`.

The function can be declared and defined at least the following way

```
int remove( void )
{
    char nameToDelete[50];

    printf("What is the name you wish to delete?\n");
    scanf("%s", nameToDelete);

    struct node *temp = node, *previous = NULL;

    while ( temp != NULL && strcmp( nameToDelete, temp->name ) != 0 )
    {
        previous = temp;
        temp = temp->next;
    }

    int success = temp != NULL;

    if ( success )
    {
        if ( previous == NULL ) node = node->next;
        else previous->next = temp->next;
    
        free( temp );
    }

    return success;
}
```

though it is better to exclude the code where the user is asked to enter a name. It is the caller of the function should provide the name to be deleted as a function argument. In this case the function will look like

```
int remove( const char *nameToDelete )
{
    struct node *temp = node, *previous = NULL;

    while ( temp != NULL && strcmp( nameToDelete, temp->name ) != 0 )
    {
        previous = temp;
        temp = temp->next;
    }

    int success = temp != NULL;

    if ( success )
    {
        if ( previous == NULL ) node = node->next;
        else previous->next = temp->next;
    
        free( temp );
    }

    return success;
}
```